# How do I link Kotlin errors to source in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, kotlin

I'm using Kotlin plugin in Android Studio, everything is working fine, except if there are any compilation errors or warning in Kotlin files during make, the resulting error messages in Messages window are not clickable - clicking them does not take you to the corresponding file (It works for errors in Java files)

Is this a bug or just something not implemented yet?
I'm using Android Studio beta 0.8.6, Build tools 20.0.0 Kotlin 0.8.11, Gradle 1.12.

Comment: This is a bug. Please report to our tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/KT Thanks

Comment: Did you file this as an issue? If so would you mind linking it? I'm using AS 1.2 and am still experiencing this issue.

Comment: The issue is filed here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5648

Comment: This issue was fixed in Kotlin M12 and later

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in Kotlin M12 and later, it is no longer an issue.

See "Fixed status of issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5648